# What is the efficient solution for computing the sum of all pair sum square in an array?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Given an Array
[image]
we need to compute
[image].
What is the running time of a time-efficient solution?

I thought the **running time** of the time-efficient solution for the equation

[image]

would be `n^2` (quadratic time) but the solution is **n (linear time)**.

Can someone explain me how is it **n (linear time)**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just you need to rewrite the formula. The inner formula is
[image].
Hence, you can take out
[image]
from the inner sum:

[image]

Now just we need to compute
[image],
[image],
and
[image].
As each of them can be done in `O(n)`, we can find the final result in `O(n)`.

Notice that, you can do it in `O(n^2)` by two nested loops (as you said). But it is not optimized. You can find similar techniques in matrix multiplication (Strassen algorihtm) as well.